# Report compression progress for ZipFIle

Tags: python, zip, progress, python-zipfile

Is it possible to monitor/report *compression progress* for `zipfile.ZipFile()`?

I found an explanation for how to monitor extraction progress [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341584/extract-zipfile-using-python-display-progress-percentage), but I guess a solution for compression must be a bit different.

Comment: There is an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28522669/11722), but it will only report on a file level. If there is only one file it would not help ( I am also looking for a solution that works when zipping single big files ).

Comment: I added an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41664456/11722) to the other question with a possible solution.

Comment: The problem is connected to the fact that the ZIP API in Python is bad. It lacks what Java has been supporting for decades. You cannot write binary data to a file inside a ZIP directly. You can only pass a file to be added. There is no callback that provides the progress.

Comment: Since we can use C in python, why don't anyone make a C level zip tool in Pip